# ActiveRecord Subquery Inner Join

Tags: ruby, activerecord, postgis, arel, rgeo

I am trying to convert a "raw" PostGIS SQL query into a Rails ActiveRecord query. My goal is to convert two sequential ActiveRecord queries (each taking ~1ms) into a single ActiveRecord query taking (~1ms). Using the SQL below with `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute` I was able to validate the reduction in time.

Thus, my direct request is to help me to convert this query into an ActiveRecord query (and the best way to execute it).

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM "users"
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT "centroid"
  FROM "zip_caches"
  WHERE "zip_caches"."postalcode" = '<postalcode>'
) AS "sub" ON ST_Intersects("users"."vendor_coverage", "sub"."centroid")
WHERE "users"."active" = 1;
```

**NOTE** that the value `<postalcode>` is the only variable data in this query. Obviously, there are two models here `User` and `ZipCache`. `User` has no direct relation to `ZipCache`.

The current two step ActiveRecord query looks like this.

```
zip = ZipCache.select(:centroid).where(postalcode: '<postalcode>').limit(1).first
User.where{st_intersects(vendor_coverage, zip.centroid)}.count
```

Comment: One of the most important tips I learnt is that while it's nice that you can chain methods in Ruby, if you're chaining in your code it indicates that you're not following the [Law Of Demeter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter). Don't start by looking at your SQL query, you should be looking at your ZipCache.select.where.limit.first and seeing how you can reduce the number of methods by moving the logic down. It's a little weird that you're approaching the query starting at ZipCache and not the User model... Am I missing something?

Comment: I would assume the piece you are "missing" is that because it is ActiveRecord chaining is required. I dare you to write an ActiveRecord query that selects and populates only one model and only one property and tell me how to do it without method chaining. Something tells me your being pedantic about LoD. It has been said many times but bears repeating [The Law of Demeter Is Not A Dot Counting Exercise](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/07/14/law-of-demeter-dot-counting.aspx/).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

*Disclamer: I've never used PostGIS*

First in your final request, it seems like you've missed the `WHERE "users"."active" = 1;` part.

Here is what I'd do:

First add a `active` scope on user (for reusability)

```
scope :active, -> { User.where(active: 1) }
```

Then for the actual query, You can have the sub query without executing it and use it in a joins on the User model, such as:

```
subquery = ZipCache.select(:centroid).where(postalcode: '<postalcode>')
User.active
    .joins("INNER JOIN (#{subquery.to_sql}) sub ON ST_Intersects(users.vendor_coverage, sub.centroid)")
    .count
```

This allow minimal raw SQL, while keeping only one query.

In any case, check the actual sql request in your console/log by setting the logger level to debug.

Comment: You need `subquery.to_sql`. Just `subquery` does not get interpolated correctly.

Answer (score 3):

The amazing tool [scuttle.io](http://www.scuttle.io/) is perfect for converting these sorts of queries:

```
User.select(Arel.star.count).where(User.arel_table[:active].eq(1)).joins(
  User.arel_table.join(ZipCach.arel_table).on(
    Arel::Nodes::NamedFunction.new(
      'ST_Intersects', [
        User.arel_table[:vendor_coverage], Sub.arel_table[:centroid]
      ]
    )
  ).join_sources
)
```

Comment: Neat, did not know about scuttle. This is the correct answer, but I'd recommend in this case just using SQL. If you're not doing algorithmic composition, you don't gain anything by writing it in ARel. It's pretty much impenetrable. `.star.count`!? `'ST_Intersects'`!? And why are some DSL methods but `NamedFunction` isn't? No one should actually write this code.

Comment: ... and not that performance matters here, but ARel is at minimum tens of method calls and vulnerable to API changes. You don't need to deal with this with SQL.